# Turn Off Auto Increment on AssemblyInfo.cs?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control, assemblies, assemblyinfo

We have a build server that is managing version numbers. When we debug we create a local build that also tries to manage the version numbers. The result is perpetual version control (SVN) conflicts in AssemblyInfo.cs that need to be resolved.

Note: we are using `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("w.x.y.z")]`, and not the wildcard mentioned by  @estebane below.

How does one turn off the auto increment feature of Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: What are you doing to create those "local" builds? Are you using some sort of build process, such as TFS, TeamCity, Jenkins, custom MSBuild scripts, which is autoincrementing the version number?

Comment: Hi @Bryan. Local builds are a SVN check out. The remote build is TeamCity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- open project properties in VS
- click the Application tab
- click "Assembly Information" button
- set both Assembly and File version
- clean solution and rebuild
- clean and rebuild projects that use your dll as reference

If this doesn't work your problem is elsewhere.

You can check the effect on these settings by finding the dll in windows explorer, right-click, select "Properties", click on "Details" tab and check the File version and Product version fields. If these behave as expected try tracking down where is your out-of-date copy that you're actually loading.

Comment: Thanks @Sten. The problem here is with Version Control (remote tinkering with AssemblyInfo.cs) and Debug Builds (local tinkering with AssemblyInfo.cs), and the perpetual conflicts of AssemblyInfo.cs. Hence the reason I want to turn off Auto Increment (and remove the source of the conflicts).

Comment: If there is remote tinkering you can't solve the problem locally with any VS setting. You have two options: Apply the same procedure for all parties participating in source control, including any source control server automation, OR remove AssemblyInfo.cs from source control and keep your local copy. In that latter scenario if you have a build server you'd still need to fix versioning there.

Answer (score 0):

In your AssemblyInfo file you can set the version and avoid auto increment using

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

If auto increment is active it looks like

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Comment: Thanks estebane. From the looks of it, I have `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]`, which is still being incremented. So how does one turn off the auto increment feature in visual studio 2010?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following to set a fixed Assembly version of 1.0.0.0 and a fixed File Version of 1.0.*.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.*")]
```

Hope this will stop incrementing your assembly version.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have another non-default software/plugin/extension updating your version number. Because Visual Studio won't do it when you don't use wildcards.

Check your Visual Studio AddIns list and Extensions list.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any pre or post build steps that are changing it?  Maybe look in the build's output window to see if that gives any indication of what process might be changing it.

If you originally have `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]` in your AssemblyInfo.cs file and it changes post build, something other than VS.NET is modifying that file.